# Check table_A before updating table_B

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an query that checks if the field 'field_A' in 'Table_A' is '0' and if it is, update 'field_B' in 'Table_B' to '10'.

I have no idea if this is even possible. I have very little experience with mysql and I'm just trying some things out. But if it is, I'd like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_B
set field_B = 10
where exists (select 1 from table_A where field_A = 0)
```